# extract airlines from flight numbers strings in excel

Tags: sql, regex, excel

I have  problem of extracting two-character code from the string format like:

```
"VA198-VA200-VA197"
```

I just want to get the string:

```
"VA-VA-VA"
```

Also the data I have are not just in one format, some data is like:

```
"DL123-DL245"
```

or

```
"DL123-VA345-HU12-OZ123"
```

Does anyone know how to do it fast in excel? Thanks.

Comment: I think you would need to use VBA here if you need this in the context of Excel.

Comment: Using VBA, you could `Split()` on hyphens to get the array, and then trim the `Left()` two characters from each item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISERR(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")),1)+0),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")),1),""))
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The formula strips out all numeric characters, leaving only the alphas and the dash.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this depending on how many possible segments their are in your string. If we assume your flight number is in A1:

```
First Segment: =LEFT(A1,2)
Second Segment: =MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2)
Third Segment: =MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1,2)
```

You could then concatenate the three expressions together and add a fourth with some conditionals. The problem is that based on your information you can have anywhere from 1 to 4 (at least) names which means you'll need a conditional:

```
Second Segment: =IF(ISERR(FIND("-",A1)),"",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2))
```

Adding in the separators we end up with something like this for up to four segements:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),IF(ISERR(FIND("-",A1)),"",CONCATENATE("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2))),IF(ISERR(FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)),"",CONCATENATE("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1,2))),IF(ISERR(FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1)),"",CONCATENATE("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1)+1,2))))
```

This will give you everything in one field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA type answer.Assuming all strings are structured in the same way. Meaning Two letters followed by numbers and separated with "-". If one such string is A1, and you want to write the result to B1:

```
Sub BreakStrings()
    d = Split(Range("A1"), "-")
    For i = LBound(d) To UBound(d)
        d(i) = Left(d(i), 2)
    Next i
    strg = Join(d, "-")
    Range("B1") = strg
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

User-defined function (UDF):

```
Function GetVal(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True: .Pattern = "(\w{2})(.+?)(?=-|$)"
        GetVal = .Replace(cell, "$1")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: It worked! I changed the pattern to (\w{2})(.+?)(?=-|$), thank you very much

Comment: @Zoe, Glad that helped! :-)